# When to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I found that `UICollectionView` is like an upgraded version of `UITableView` introduced in iOS6, but when should I choose `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`?

There are still Apps using `UITableView`, if `UICollectionView` can do anything `UITableView` can do , why people still use `UITableView`? Is there a difference as far as performance is concerned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

That depends on the requirements. How the application flows determines which type of UI to integrate into the application.

People mainly use the `UICollectionview` for creating types of UIs with multiple images shown in a grid. This would have complex logic using `UITableView`, but with `UICollectionview`, it would be easy.

When using `UICollectionview`, you don't need to set buttons with tags or other things by getting selected items values. You can simply get `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and in `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
```

You get the selected row instead of the item, so for creating grid or modified items, using `UICollectionview` is best.

For the listing details of each item, people use `UITableView` because it shows more info on each item.

**Apple Docs:**

[UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts. Collection views support customizable layouts that can be used to implement multi-column grids, tiled layouts, circular layouts, and many more. You can even change the layout of a collection view dynamically if you want.

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> A table view displays a list of items in a single column. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, which allows users to scroll through the table, although UITableView allows vertical scrolling only. The cells comprising the individual items of the table are UITableViewCell objects; UITableView uses these objects to draw the visible rows of the table. Cells have content—titles and images—and can have, near the right edge, accessory views. Standard accessory views are disclosure indicators or detail disclosure buttons; the former leads to the next level in a data hierarchy and the latter leads to a detailed view of a selected item. Accessory views can also be framework controls, such as switches and sliders, or can be custom views. Table views can enter an editing mode where users can insert, delete, and reorder rows of the table.

Comment: I think in terms of extendibility - Collection view scores more!!

Comment: I'm wondering why one ever need to use tableview when collectionview can serve all the needs without additional complexity but provides flexibility (if a customer ever needs to extend layout to more than one column, it would be pretty straight forward to do that with collectionview). I was always using tableviews by default but now I doubt if that makes sense to switch to collectionviews instead. Am I missing something?

Comment: its all based on main requirement. Collection view introduce late and till then all dev use table to make grid and that kind of stuff. but now a days collectionview is most populor to use for making layout like tableview. as well so i dont think its a bad idea to use collectionviews

Answer (score 54):

Here's my criteria:

- If a UITableView can do it, use it
- If a UITableView needs lots of code to do it or can't do it at all, use UICollectionView.

You have to consider the restrictions on UITableView before making a decision: It's a single column. And you can only customize the cells, but not section backgrounds and such. So if you have a straight-up list of things with no extra frills - that looks like a bog standard iOS view, basically - then use UITableview. If you have custom insets, or a border around each section, use UICollectionView.

<del>I'm actually considering UICollectionView for all things simply because it's very expensive when you start developing your view as a table view, then later find out it can't do that one thing that you need it to do. 1st hand experience ;)</del>

Edit after even more experience with the two: Disregard that last paragraph. UICollectionView requires a lot of boilerplate code to make it work like a UITableView. Use UICollectionView only when really needed. ;)

Comment: Perfect answer I was looking for! This should be voted more!

Comment: Disclosing your personal experience and recommendations is very helpful!

Comment: I definitely chuckled reading this, well-said! UITableView is just as customizable as anything, except it will crash if you add animations that offset the queuing. I would recommend your answer to go with the Animations guide, and some digging to personally learn how many internal views exist so you can refresh them, and the "I can't make the separator line invisible" issue you eventually find won't surprise anyone. Hidden views in scrollView, UIButton, and tableView throw most customizations off until you know they're hidden in the things

Answer (score 40):

For simple lists and forwards/backwards navigtaion, use `UITableView`.

If you need a high degree of customisability, use `UICollectionView`.

Generally speaking, in software development, it's best to choose the approach which represents "The Simplest Possible Thing".

EDIT: As of iOS 14, `UICollectionView` can now do lists as well and is now the recommended approach. See this session from WWDC20 for more information and implementation details: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10026/

Answer (score 16):

According to my point of view main difference between collectionView and tableView is that

> TABLEVIEW        --> show list of items in only one column.
>
> COLLECTION-VIEW   -->show list of items in multiple column.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 11):

If you choose UITableView for iPhone, make sure you have considered your iPad strategy first. If you want an iPad-specific layout, you may want that single-column layout to become a grid.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's not required, I always use a collectionview.  That way I can easily adapt how my collections are presented for differing resolutions.  A plus is that it's ready to quickly add new types of cells when refactoring in the future.

I see no point of tableviews.  It's very simple to use a collection view to represent a table.  IMO.

Answer (score 5):

From my personal experience the two elements should only be compared loosly.

**TableView**

A TableView is a UI element designed for showing data in a list format. There is certain functionality that comes as standard with a UITableView, such as:

- Accessory View
- Cell Selection Style
- Editting Style (Delete and edit buttons).

The above elements enhance the usability of data when displaying and interacting in a list format. Such as viewing emails.

**CollectionView**

A CollectionView is a UI element designed for showing content using a custom layout (usually anything that isn't a list). CollectionViews improve functionality of displaying data in completely bespoke layout styles and also dynamically changing layouts on the fly. Some examples are:

- Horizonal Lists
- Photo Galleries
- Thumbnail views
- Carousels
- Dials
- Laying out elements on a map
- etc.

CollectionViews also allow for multiple selections.

**Conclusion**

As you can see from the above, both have completely different use cases and are designed for enhancing the development and usability of their own specific data sets.

If you are looking at displaying anything in a list style with the followin interactions: 
- Adding
- Deleting
- Re-ordering
Then a UITableView will simplify this process by providing the support straight out of the box.

Anything else, you should leverage the benefits of CollectionView as you have more flexibility.

Comment: TableViews also allow for multiple selections.

Comment: @BenStoller - TableViews don't respond to selections the same way a CollectionView does - As standard, a TableView accepts one selection via didSelectCell. Multiple selections that you see in features such as multiple item delete are custom built and not offered out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

Its totally dependent on how your data to be shown. 
As mentioned by many above, if you require only single set of data and that too not complex, go for `UITableView` else use `UICollectionView`.

`UICollectionView` is customization friendly.

If you are dealing with multiple cell heights or so, then go for `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 2):

Both are depends on the requirements. Table Views also have support for a variety of editing scenarios. This support has not been implemented in the Collection View classes.
If you are converting from a Table View that relies on these methods, expect to do a little extra heavy lifting in the Collection View.
Collection View section headers can be placed anywhere within the view.
and UITableView don't need to set buttons with tags or other things by getting selected items values.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, everyone uses UICollectionView that I've come across, when they only need a UITableView. "It's one-dimensional. It goes up and down. Why are you adding unnecessary delegate methods for layout AND data?". I once spent an extra 2 hours helping a startup find out why their UICollectionViewCell got squished because the owner, who didn't read the Animations manual, nor HIG, nor the UICollectionView guide, decided to use it and add variable heights and anims. Needless to say, he gave himself a headache and much lost time on a non-business-critical issue he could have avoided by simply using a table cell, since there's no extra layout delegate + Nib.

Let me get this straight, I am all for UICollectionView's when your data and display need it. They're very powerful. But in practice, most people I've seen have been using them on lists.

This brings up another flaw. They're also used on short, constant lists that won't change, ever. In this case, just make a Xib. Or write a custom view that stacks them. Why? Because you don't need the memory management for 5 sets of labels with a button or switch. If they might change, then yes, use a list. If you want physics, then UICollectionView works well with a some cool effects. But do you really need to add 5 delegate methods and a layout system for 5 labels that will never move?

Also, I'm not forgetting that iOS has a native stacking view now too. I can never get it to deform how I want, even though I'm quite adept at the 2D and animation systems, so I never use the built-in one.

All I'm saying is, define your requirements. Maybe you don't need either of these, if your UI isn't adding/removing items and refreshing itself. Or maybe you want to write a Card Game and throw them out virtually on a table, then use UICollectionView with a physics system for its layout guide.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the UICollectionView can do most of the work which UITableview can do. well, at the same time, it's more complex to use.

I suggest you use UICollectionView as TableView just in case your manager change requirements in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our need we are choosing TableView or CollectionView.

Example:

> For phone contacts tableView is best option.
>
> For photo gallery, collection view will be best option.

Comment: Whilst I agree the way this has been put seems more like an opinion and I think it should just be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my current project. Which to use. In my case it was simple really. I needed both. I needed my view to look like UITableView and also to change its change / layout. So, UICollectionView was used. I also use UITableView everywhere I don't need any extra customisation. Since UiTableView comes with a default layout that includes images and text - I use it for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our requirement we choose UITableView or UICollection view.

If we want to display images or items in grid type or if we need more customisability we use UICollectionview.

For listing each item with details and subdetails we use UITableView.

**UICollectionView:**
  The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts.

**UITableView:** A table view displays a list of items in a single column. UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, which allows users to scroll through the table, although UITableView allows vertical scrolling only.

Answer (score 0):

As per my view for Grid View display use UI Collection View.All other list view use UITable View