# What are the disadvantages of using UICollectionView for single column?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Are there any disadvantages to using a UICollectionView for a single column view (almost exactly like a UITableView) instead of a UITableView? I am currently implementing the view as single column, but may want to change it to two column. I want to know if it would make sense to initially use a UICollectionView as a single column and then switch it to two column if necessary.

Comment: Unless you don't require multicolumn use UITableView. And if it is require in the future for multicolumn it is easy to move. For more detail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078847/when-to-use-uicollectionview-instead-of-uitableview

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation - `The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts.`

`UICollectionView` is actually intended for showing multi dimensional data, its main advantage over `UITableView` is its reusability, which is actually your current scenarios.

You can reuse it in a way that won't require major restructuring of the code.