# How to implement the following table?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'd like to implement the following view (circled blue):

[image]

However, I'm not sure what view to use.

On the one hand, when using a `UITableView`, the cells' width cannot be changed.

On the other hand, when using a `UICollectionView`, I need to have sections (exactly three sections; each section represents a game state, either 'running', 'waiting' or 'ended').

Cells shall be added dynamically (the data for the cells is retrieved through an API).

What is the preferred basic structure (basically the view) to use?

I'm not looking for a fully coded solution! I'd just like to know what view I should be using.

Comment: Could you at least be so kind and state why this question is bad if you're downvoting, please? Otherwise I won't learn from mistakes.

Comment: The question is downvoted because similar questions were asked many times before and a simple search will give you a lot of [results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uitableview+vs+uicollectionview&t=osx&ia=web).
Like [#161: UITableView vs. UICollectionView](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/161-uitableview-vs-uicollectionview) from Little Bites of Cocoa or even on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078847/when-to-use-uicollectionview-instead-of-uitableview).

Comment: Makes kind of sense. Although this question is more specific and it's not as general as "When to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView?". This is linked to a certain existing layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a simple one-column set of cells, it looks like a table view would be a good fit. A collection view can do everything a table view can, but it's more work.

I'd suggest using a sectioned table view with section headers, and a custom header view that's mostly transparent and shows the background behind it. (The section header's view would still be the same width as all the other cells, but it would be transparent, have a fill color of clear, and have a subview that draws the boxes with your section headers in it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about the content (can't understand that language) but looks like a quiz app?

The basic outline for displaying the majority of the dataset looks to be a `UITableView` in grouped mode (where "Warten Auf" and "Beendete Spiele" are groups).

If the first row (under the green button) is part of the data set you can either leave that without a section/group header, use the green button as a header view for that group or use the green button as a header view for the `UITableView` itself.

Comment: `looks like a quiz app` indeed, it is! I just considered the content as unimportant (that's German, btw). `use the green button as a header view`, yeah, thanks, that's probably what I'll go for.