# UITableView vs UICollectionView for list display

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I need to display a simple list where each cell has a title and subtitle and an accessory view. Height of a cell may be variable depending on subtitle length. This was easy to display using UITableView. But I saw a more modern way is to display such a list is UICollectionView with list configuration. There are a number of videos on list configuration & diffable data source and number of tutorials as well on the same but what I am trying to understand is if Apple is telling developers to move to UICollectionView from UITableView (which some experts surmise is going to be deprecated given the new APIs). So my question is whether one should abandon UITableView to display such a list mentioned above, and if UICollectionView is really a replacement for UITableView?

Answer (score 1):

Apple started killing UITableViews years ago, likely 5 or so. They're still here and still going strong. UITableViews will still work and there's absolutely no reason for you to drop them and replace them with UICollectionViews.

Comment: See comment from another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23078999 - it references the video from WWDC20 in which building lists via collection views is talked about. But yes, it appears that UITableViews are still commonly used.